# Can't create list custom settings (have they been deprecated?)

Tags: customsetting, custom-metadata

The option to select the "List" type on the new custom settings screen is not available (disabled and set to "Hierarchy.") I see a notification to use Custom Metadata types, however they will not work for this particular application because the data will need to be modified by a test class.

Is there a way to create new list custom settings?

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't delete duplicate questions. They act as useful signposts. Also it reflects negatively on your account to have deleted questions.